Взаимное содержание двух классов
Суть ситуации: я создаю игру, в которой есть персонажи(class Character), и есть разнообразные предметы(class Item), которые эти персонажи могут носить с собой. Но так же и есть предметы, из которых могут появится персонажи и мне нужно заранее знать, какой персонаж появится из конкретного предмета, учитывая, что появляющийся персонаж, так же может иметь какие-то предметы.
Каким образом это реализовать?
Я пытался реализовать это так - есть два класса, необходимо, чтобы в первом классе содержался экземпляр второго, а во втором - экземпляр первого.
При такой реализации компилятор ругается на зацикленность:
public class Item
{
   int id;
   Character mob = new Character();
}

public class Character
{
   int name;
   Item charInventory = new Item();
}


Обычная передача через конструктор или свойство. Но замечу, что у вас тут есть нарушение, логическое нарушение, ибо подумайте логически, яблоко, которое лежит в пакете, знает что либо про вас (человека)? Нет... Почему тогда у вас вдруг "предмет" знает что-то про персонажа? А в  будущем там еще и будут небось действия, которые будут влиять на персонажа. Ну, это, странно)

Невозможно. C# не поддерживает композиции классов. В вашей реализации экземпляры создаваемых классов не содержатся друг в друге. Поля этих классов предствляют собой ссылки на экземпляры другого класса. Ну и проблема с зацикленностью. Тут она получается за счет безконечной рекурсии при создании эеземпляров. Но она никуда бы не делась, если бы C# поддерживал композицию классов. ¿Каков по-вашему будет размер экземпляра Item, который содержит в себе экземпляр Character, который содержит в себе экземпляр Item, который содержит в себе экземпляр Character...?

Смысл такой логики, образно говоря, в том, что у меня есть предмет(Item) - яйцо и я должен заранее знать кто из него вылупится(Character), и этот "птенец" так же может иметь какие-то предметы(Item).

Ну вот, у вас получается проблема XY. Вот про это и стоило спрашивать в вопросе. Стоит его отредактировать, добавить релевантный код и постановку проблемы.

@user7860670 упоминая XY, всегда давайте ссылку на Мету. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567

В C# классы являются ссылочными типами и их экзепляры содержатся в куче. Соответственно поле в классе может содержать в себе только ссылку на экземпляр другого класса, а не сам экзепляр другого класса.
Далее, в приведенном коде компилятор справедливо ругается на зацикленность, так как при создании экзепляра Item при инициализации поля mob будет создан экземпляр Character, при создании экземпляра которого будет инициализировано поле charInventory и будет создан еще один экземпляр Item и т.д. Чтобы избавиться от этого достаточно просто разорвать рекурсию и не создавать экземпляры другого класса автоматически при инициализации поля, оставляя ссылку нулевой, либо делегируя создание экземпляра внешнему коду:
public class Item
{
    public int id;
    public Character? mob;

    public Item(int initial_id)
    {
        this.id = initial_id;
        this.mob = null;
    }
   
    public Item(int initial_id, Character initial_mob)
    {
        this.id = initial_id;
        this.mob = initial_mob;
    }
}

public class Character
{
    public int id;
    public Item? item;

    public Character(int initial_id)
    {
        this.id = initial_id;
        this.item = null;
    }
   
    public Character(int initial_id, Item initial_item)
    {
        this.id = initial_id;
        this.item = initial_item;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var empty_egg = new Item(0); // mob будет null 
        var chicken = new Character(1, empty_egg);
        var cage = new Item(2, chicken);
        var peon = new Character(3, cage);
    }
}

online compiler
